# Access a webservice through an MS SQL assemby

Tags: sql-server, web-services, permissions, .net-assembly

This question I think is related to the access of SQL accounts.

I created a visual studio project in which I created a dll that was placed as a stored procedure in SQL. The visual studio project consumes twice a webservice.

The DLLs are installed with access external_acess.

When installing on my local SQL (windows 7) everything works correctly. When calling the webservice it is called perfectly. The user that is running SQL is local system.

After placing these same DLLs and install them on another SQL server (windows server 2003) does not consume the webservice. In SQL also uses the location system.

If switching to the user network system that SQL consumes the webservices.

The question is: Where do I set this access (acess to consume webservices or http acess)? or how do I check it?

Thanks

Comment: Check if the webservice is accessible from the server, by using the browser.

Comment: It's possible to enter in the computer with the localsystem account?